# how to formally described this algorithm for turing machine?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics, turing-machines

**Waring**: This task was given by my professor who is 80 y/o and nobody understands what he sometimes wants, I do not expect more less standard approach to this problem, not just because the problem is difficult, but because my professor is old-school ex-ussr crazy guy ;) (he likes to make easy things complicated, just to explain why this is posted here)

This task is pure theory one, but I do not know how to formalize it with words
Problem:

> 9 bits binary code is given on input, we have to print "0" in output
>   if amount of bits with value "1" are two times less than amount of
>   bits with value "0", if this condition is false that we have to print
>   "1" in output.

What I proposed in my description is to introduce a counter, and then count bits that have value 1, then make an output based on this counter, but I was claimed to be an idiot and I was told that there's the way without the counter and I choose the hardest way. Does someone know the better way to determine what to output?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if description looks messy

Comment: If you're writing out an actual Turing machine, keeping a counter is hard, but encoding the finite set of possible states of the counter is easy.

Comment: What your teacher wants is that you understand to not use hammer to kill a fly; don't bother your teacher is too old, always first think of him as a wise person. Computer engineering is about expertise on which right tool can be used to solve a problem, not only to naively solve a problem. Here, a simple automaton is far better adequate. Finally, no this is not a pure theoretical problem, it is about the way you can tackle streamed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the TM reads the input bits, the state number must capture the number of bits seen, from 0 through to 9, so that we can recognize when we get to the end, and the number of 1 bits seen, with the relevant cases being 0, 1, 2, 3, and >=4.

There are less than 10*5=50 states required to encode all the relevant possibilities.  When the machine enters one of the states indicating that 9 input bits have been seen, it writes a 0 if it indicates that 3 1s have been seen, or 1 otherwise, then stops.

Note that we didn't need to use the tape for storage -- the input language is regular so it can be decided with a finite state machine and unbounded storage is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

While Matt is correct, you can generalize this problem to arbitrary input sizes using storage.

1. Go to the beginning of the tape
2. Move forward looking for an unmarked `1`. Mark it.

   - If you can't find an unmarked `1`, go to step 7.
3. Go back to the beginning of the tape
4. Look for an unmarked `0`. Mark it.

   - If you can't find an unmarked `0`, go to step 9.
5. Look for another unmarked `0`. Mark it.

   - If you can't find an unmarked `0`, go to step 9.
6. Go to step 1
7. Go to the beginning of your input.
8. Look for an unmarked `0`.

   - If you don't find one, output `0`. Halt.
9. Output `1`. Halt.

This will work for any input size. Intuitively, we're looking for 2 `0`s for every `1` in the input, making sure there are twice as many `0` bits as `1` bits.